# XeLaTeX inside chroot jail

Tags: xetex, security

I'm using xetex `3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)`.
I'm trying to run xelatex inside chroot jail.

I've copied following binaries and directories:

```
pdftex
bibtex
xdvipdfmx
xelatex

/usr/share/tex-common/  
/usr/share/texlive-base 
/usr/share/texlive-bin  
/usr/share/texmf        
/usr/share/texmf-texlive
/usr/share/fonts        
/var/lib/tex-common     
/var/lib/texmf          
/etc/texmf              
/etc/fonts
```

Also I tried to copy another tex binaries (`tex latex pdflatex xetex`) but it's not helped.

When I try to compile minimal xelatex sample

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

everything is fine in standard environment, but when I try to compile it inside chroot jail I have (pdf file not produced)

```
Error 32512 (driver return code) generating output;
file simple.pdf may not be valid.
```

If I compile it with `-no-pdf` option everything is fine, `xdv` file produced.

When I run `xdvipdfmx -vvv simple.xdv` I have no warnings or errors and even get pdf, but process finished with 139 exit code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess that `xdvipdfmx` needs `gs`

Comment: @egreg: not true; I haven't had GhostScript installed and XeTeX has worked fine. Grigory: I guess one option could be to download texlive and point the install script into the to-be-chrooted directory.

Comment: @morbusg Nice to know. One should at least know what the exit code 139 means.

Comment: @egreg I've added `gs` to jail but it's not helped: the same behaviour. @morbusg installing texlive not an option by requirements, but thanks for idea!

Comment: Have you `ldd`'ed all the binaries to make sure all the libraries are included?

Comment: @morbusg yes, I checked `ldd` output twice. Btw I solved the problem

Comment: @morbusg we found large sample with large images and it doesn't compile without `gs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem. Here is the list of missing dependencies:

- `/bin/sh`
- `/usr/bin/basename` - used by `xdvipdfmx`
- `/usr/bin/gs` - sometimes needed for images processing
- `/tmp` - prevents segfaults

Also useful dependencies:

- `/proc` and `/etc/ld.so.cache` - prevent complaining of xetex about "can't open file for reading"